# Should I remove clustered index from surrogate keys?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

From what I understand, an advantage of a clustered index is that it's faster to seek something there if it's part of the indexed columns as the rows are stored 'close'. Since SQL Server automatically makes primary keys as 'clustered index', is it not true that using a clustered index for something that has no meaning like a surrogate key removes this advantage, and instead I should make the natural key the clustered index?

Comment: If you're going to change to a natural key, wouldn't you just drop the identity column altogether?

Comment: The 'natural key' would be a 3 column set, so I prefer having a surrogate key in this case, but then I started thinking that most of the times I would be searching by the natural key so that's why I would think making that the clustered index would be better. There wouldn't be any 'mass insertions' on this table so the hot spot problem mentioned wouldn't apply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal attributes you want in a clustered index key are: static, narrow, increasing and unique.

Normally a natural key will not be narrow and increasing.

Often a natural key will not be static (like a phone number), although it probably will be unique.  Often it won't be particularly narrow (like a GUID or a license plate) compared to an int or bigint.

A table is either a clustered index or a heap.

A clustered index is the choice of key for organizing the entirety of the table's data.  It is not a separate index like a non-clustered index.

A surrogate key is often a good choice for a clustered index if it is an IDENTITY, for example.

If it is a GUID, probably not, unless it is a SEQUENTIALID.

You can see why you want this clustered index key to be static because you don't want the data rows moving around.  Any time a key changes, you would also have to worry about maintaining the referential integrity.  I prefer any keys for references to be static anyway, because cascading updates/delete can also ripple through your data model - and for what benefit, really when you could have a static surrogate and not have to bother with all those re-writes?

There are advantages to clustering on other keys if large chunks of the data are going to be read according to that key.

To answer your question - I would say no, but post your table design and usage scenarios.

Comment: added a bit more info as comment to the question

Comment: thinking about it from the two responses (both great, thanks Aaron too!) I'm going with leaving the identity surrogate key as clustered. I didn't know a clustered index wasn't really an index but just how the table is stored, so doesn't make sense for the table rows to be rearranged whenever a new row is added.

Comment: I've got a similar scenario where I've got a surrogate key which is used for row uniqueness but it's really not what the table is queried on, it's primarily queried on other fields e.g. either by date only or another field and date - would you say that's a reasonable scenario to ditch the clustered index on the PK and perhaps use it on one of the other fields (or possibly a combination)?

Comment: @James Depends - however, if inserts are all over the place, then... you are going to have page splits.  But for retrieval of ranges, that may make sense... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190639(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 6):

There is no right or wrong answer here, as it depends. Advantages of clustering, say, an IDENTITY column that is a primary key, as opposed to clustering on something else, include:

- elimination of "bad" page splits, since increasing values are always inserted at the "end" of the table/partition (this introduces "hot spots" - which may become an issue if you are inserting at a very high rate).
- no lookups required when a seek or scan is used to find a row or range - if you use a non-clustered index to identify a row, lookups may be necessary to retrieve any non-covered columns.
- an `INT` is 4 bytes (and less if you use data compression). So when you have child tables that reference this table, it is quite useful for the primary key to be skinny so that the repeated information in the child tables is also skinny. Having it clustered doesn't have a ton of bearing on this, but it seems like a hand-wavy solution to use a natural key for the clustered index but then perform joins to child tables using the non-clustered surrogate key. In most solutions I've seen, the surrogate is clustered (and distributed throughout the model), and the natural key is simply made unique.

Whether you have a better candidate for the clustering key, who knows? We don't know your application or even what type of data you're thinking about for the natural key. What is the data model? What is the natural key? Is it likely to change? Is it large? Is it really unique?

As an aside, I like to think that SQL Server creates `PRIMARY KEY` as `CLUSTERED` by default because (a) most tables should have a clustered index and (b) in most cases the key should be clustered (but not all!).

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with SQL for over 20 years and have always found that using a surrogate key(identity column) for the primary key or unique clustered index doesn’t make a lot of sense and just hurts performance. I would highly recommend you make it on a natural key

To me the first point of the primary key/clustered index is to define to anyone who uses your table what constitutes a unique entity. When you use an identity column you do not really enforce real uniqueness since an identity column will obviously always be unique. Many times, I have run into tables with a primary key on an identity column that is a mess with duplicates and bad data.

Also, any non-clustered index you create will automatically include whatever column(s) you chose as the clustered index, so that it can do key lookups when necessary. So it would be very beneficial for many queries to include the natural key with non-clustered indexes.

I mean sure if you’re absolutely worried about space an integer identity might save you the most space but performance wise making the primary key on natural keys will be the best for data integrity and performance.

I often see many doctrinaire answers from people who haven’t spent years fixing bugs in code and making code as fast as possible, but are just repeating what they read in a book. I still sometimes may add an identity column, because they're useful for some queries, but I do not use it as the clustered index/primary key.